# CSS nav menu vertical center <LI>s

Tags: css, navigation

I have a navigation menu with css. I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center the li elements.
I have them centered horizontally, but can't get them centered vertically... especially since they can be multi-line (ie: Bath&
Kitchen) vs single-line (ie: Plumbing)...

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd4Az/)**

**CSS:**

```
 #menu { 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: center;
 }

 #menu li {
      float: left; 
      position: relative; 
      width: 75px; 
      height: 30px; 
      margin-right: 2px; 
      background-color: #994708;
 }

 #menu li a {
      color: #FFFFFF; 
      display: block; 
      position: relative; 
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 75px; 
      height: 30px; 
      font-size: 11px; 
      line-height: 12px; 
      text-transform: uppercase; 
      text-decoration: none;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">All<br />Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New<br />Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plumbing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bath &<br />Kitchen</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a special class to handle the single line menu items. I just wrote some code in the databinding and checked if there was a "line break" in the text. If so, apply the special class.

Answer (score 1):

Added `top: 40%;` to the `#menu li a`. Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/rd4Az/2/).

Comment: Thanks but this does not truly center. I see the single line and multi line remain aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, I made couple of modifications to the code, I think the only way would be applying a special class.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dCpHH/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to avoid a special class if possible since this menu will be database driven. Any other ideas?

Comment: SKS's method might be a solution, but won't have the best design outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menu li {
      float: left; 
      position: relative; 
      margin-right:2px;   <--removed redundant entries, moved some to A
}

#menu li a {
      color: #FFFFFF; 
      background-color: #994708;
      display: table-cell;    <--- added this
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 75px; 
      height: 30px; 
      font-size: 11px; 
      line-height: 12px;
      text-transform: uppercase; 
      text-decoration: none;
 }
```